# XPath : All divs which not have a specific child

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm have HTML file and I'm parsing it with XPath. I'm want to select all [div] nodes which not have [p] tag(s) in it.

For example, input:

```
<div>
    <p>no1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>no2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    yes!!!
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
yes!!!
```

I'm tried this XPath query, which not working for me:

```
//div[not (p)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use //div[not(descendant::p)]

Here's a quick XSL sample

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
<div>
<xsl:for-each select='//div[not(descendant::p)]'>
    <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Maybe add some information that `p` is equal to `child:p` or `./p` and only matches children. While `descendant::p` or `.//p` match all descendant nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath:

```
//div[not (p)]
```

returns 2 `div` Nodes in your sample xml:

```
<div>  <-- This one
    <div>
```

and your expected one:

```
<div>
    yes!!!
</div>
```

You are possibly referencing the xpath in a query where you are expecting just a single node (e.g. `SelectSingleNode`) and therefore just the first node is returned.